# Как расположить объекты?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, позиционирование

Здравствуйте появилась опять проблема в позиционировании.
Не понимаю почему так происходит, когда добавляю значение float: left;, чтобы расположить объекты в строчку, следующие исчезаю со страницы. почему так, объясните пожалуйста, буду очень признателен.

Надо расположить объекты col-sm-4 в строку по 3, а col-sm-6 по 2, и если не сложно, то дайте пожалуйста советы по коду, может быть что-то улучшить в плане кода.

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
.h1,
.h2,
.h3,
.h4,
.h5,
.h6 {
    font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif!important;
}

/* body:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transform-origin: center;
  background-size: cover;
} */

ul.nav {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin: 0;
  height: 70px;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

ul.nav li {
    font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif!important;
    width: 140px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: inline; /* Отображать как строчный элемент */
    margin-right: 17px; /* Отступ слева */
    border: 1px solid #000; /* Рамка вокруг текста */
}

ul.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #49505F
}

ul.nav a {
  height: 52px;
  width: 140px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  /* line-height: 20px; */
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #383E4C;
  border: 1px solid #646D7C;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #383E4C;
  margin: 0;
  height: 80px;
}

header {width: 100%; height: auto;}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.title {
  font-family: "Open Sans";;
  color: #f0f0f0; /* Цвет текста, совпадает с цветом фона */
  text-shadow: #fff -1px -1px 0,
              #333 2px 2px 0;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 3.2em;
  /* text-transform: uppercase; */
}

.title h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
}

.title h4 {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.slide-content {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.col-sm-4 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

.col-sm-6 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.feature-content {
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
}

.feature-area {
  position: relative;
}

#blog-area {
  margin: 60px 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.blog-content {
  background-color: #F2F2F2;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <nav class="navbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="section1">Homepage</a></li>
            <li><a href="section2">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="section3">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="section4">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="section5">External</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div id="section1">
      <div class="col-sm-0">
        <div class="img">
          <img src="img/bg-1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <h1>CONQUER</h1>
          <h4>Simple Bootstrap Template</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div id="section2">
      <section id="feature-area" class="about-section">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="feature-content">
            <img src="img/1-1.jpg" alt="Image">
            <h2 class="feature-content-title green-text">Bootstrap v3.3.6</h2>
            <p class="feature-content-description">Morbi sagittis justo a velit placerat ullamcorper quis quis velit. Sed convallis at risus ullamcorper auctor. Praesent quis velit neque. Quisque semper porta nisi vitae suscipit. Duis lectus magna, ornare ac scelerisque.
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="feature-content-link green-btn">button green</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="feature-content">
          <img src="img/1-2.jpg" alt="Image">
          <h2 class="feature-content-title blue-text">Responsive Design</h2>
          <p class="feature-content-description">Conquer Template is provided by templatemo for free of charge. You can use this template for any kind of website. No credit link is required. All images by <a href="http://unsplash.com" target="_parent">Unsplash</a>. Thank you for visiting our website. Please come again!</p>
          <a href="#" class="feature-content-link blue-btn">See Details</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="feature-content">
            <img src="img/1-3.jpg" alt="Image">
            <h2 class="feature-content-title red-text">Parallax Layout</h2>
            <p class="feature-content-description">Morbi sagittis justo a velit placerat ullamcorper quis quis velit. Sed convallis at risus ullamcorper auctor. Praesent quis velit neque. Quisque semper porta nisi vitae suscipit. Duis lectus magna, ornare ac scelerisque.
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="feature-content-link red-btn">Button Red</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section id="blog-area">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-center inner">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="blog-content">
                  <img src="img/2-1.jpg" alt="Image">
                  <h2>Two Column Left Side</h2>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tempor eros eget eros maximus, ut cursus sem euismod. Donec iaculis tristique odio at consectetur. Nullam dignissim varius suscipit. Sed in leo sit amet velit finibus pretium.<br><br>
                    Vestibulum vel mauris at erat mattis accumsan et ac lorem. Cras non venenatis orci, sed tincidunt massa. Duis nisl lectus, auctor eu sodales at, dignissim eu orci. Sed vitae venenatis magna, in blandit metus.</p>
                    <br>

                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="blog-content">
                    <img src="img/2-2.jpg" alt="Image">
                    <h2>Two Column Right Side</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tempor eros eget eros maximus, ut cursus sem euismod. Donec iaculis tristique odio at consectetur. Nullam dignissim varius suscipit. Sed in leo sit amet velit finibus pretium.<br><br>
                    Vestibulum vel mauris at erat mattis accumsan et ac lorem. Cras non venenatis orci, sed tincidunt massa. Duis nisl lectus, auctor eu sodales at, dignissim eu orci. Sed vitae venenatis magna, in blandit metus.</p>
                      <span><a href="#">read more</a></span><br>
                      <p id="blofr"></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </section>
          </div>
        </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз уж Вы используете 4-й Бутстрап, не надо добавлять блокам float: left - просто оберните их в row, и всё заработает:

```css
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
.h1,
.h2,
.h3,
.h4,
.h5,
.h6 {
    font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif!important;
}

/* body:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transform-origin: center;
  background-size: cover;
} */

ul.nav {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin: 0;
  height: 70px;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

ul.nav li {
    font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif!important;
    width: 140px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: inline; /* Отображать как строчный элемент */
    margin-right: 17px; /* Отступ слева */
    border: 1px solid #000; /* Рамка вокруг текста */
}

ul.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #49505F;
}

ul.nav a {
  height: 52px;
  width: 140px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  /* line-height: 20px; */
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #383E4C;
  border: 1px solid #646D7C;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #383E4C;
  margin: 0;
  height: 80px;
}

header {width: 100%; height: auto;}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.title {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  color: #f0f0f0; /* Цвет текста, совпадает с цветом фона */
  text-shadow: #fff -1px -1px 0,
              #333 2px 2px 0;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 3.2em;
  /* text-transform: uppercase; */
}

.title h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
}

.title h4 {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.slide-content {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.col-sm-4 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.col-sm-6 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.feature-content {
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
}

.feature-area {
  position: relative;
}

#blog-area {
  margin: 60px 0px;
  position: relative;
}

.blog-content {
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <nav class="navbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="section1">Homepage</a></li>
            <li><a href="section2">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="section3">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="section4">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="section5">External</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div id="section1">
      <div class="col-sm-0">
        <div class="img">
          <img src="img/bg-1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="title">
          <h1>CONQUER</h1>
          <h4>Simple Bootstrap Template</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div id="section2">
      <section id="feature-area" class="about-section">
      <div class="row">
     
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="feature-content">
            <img src="img/1-1.jpg" alt="Image">
            <h2 class="feature-content-title green-text">Bootstrap v3.3.6</h2>
            <p class="feature-content-description">Morbi sagittis justo a velit placerat ullamcorper quis quis velit. Sed convallis at risus ullamcorper auctor. Praesent quis velit neque. Quisque semper porta nisi vitae suscipit. Duis lectus magna, ornare ac scelerisque.
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="feature-content-link green-btn">button green</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="feature-content">
          <img src="img/1-2.jpg" alt="Image">
          <h2 class="feature-content-title blue-text">Responsive Design</h2>
          <p class="feature-content-description">Conquer Template is provided by templatemo for free of charge. You can use this template for any kind of website. No credit link is required. All images by <a href="http://unsplash.com" target="_parent">Unsplash</a>. Thank you for visiting our website. Please come again!</p>
          <a href="#" class="feature-content-link blue-btn">See Details</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="feature-content">
            <img src="img/1-3.jpg" alt="Image">
            <h2 class="feature-content-title red-text">Parallax Layout</h2>
            <p class="feature-content-description">Morbi sagittis justo a velit placerat ullamcorper quis quis velit. Sed convallis at risus ullamcorper auctor. Praesent quis velit neque. Quisque semper porta nisi vitae suscipit. Duis lectus magna, ornare ac scelerisque.
            </p>
            <a href="#" class="feature-content-link red-btn">Button Red</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <section id="blog-area">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row text-center inner">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="blog-content">
                  <img src="img/2-1.jpg" alt="Image">
                  <h2>Two Column Left Side</h2>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tempor eros eget eros maximus, ut cursus sem euismod. Donec iaculis tristique odio at consectetur. Nullam dignissim varius suscipit. Sed in leo sit amet velit finibus pretium.<br><br>
                    Vestibulum vel mauris at erat mattis accumsan et ac lorem. Cras non venenatis orci, sed tincidunt massa. Duis nisl lectus, auctor eu sodales at, dignissim eu orci. Sed vitae venenatis magna, in blandit metus.</p>
                    <br>

                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="blog-content">
                    <img src="img/2-2.jpg" alt="Image">
                    <h2>Two Column Right Side</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam tempor eros eget eros maximus, ut cursus sem euismod. Donec iaculis tristique odio at consectetur. Nullam dignissim varius suscipit. Sed in leo sit amet velit finibus pretium.<br><br>
                    Vestibulum vel mauris at erat mattis accumsan et ac lorem. Cras non venenatis orci, sed tincidunt massa. Duis nisl lectus, auctor eu sodales at, dignissim eu orci. Sed vitae venenatis magna, in blandit metus.</p>
                      <span><a href="#">read more</a></span><br>
                      <p id="blofr"></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </section>
          </div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Благодарю за оказанную помощь. А как быть, если бы я был без бутстрапа 4?

Comment: @Proger0912, ну, можно использовать 3-й - он как раз на флоатах: то есть там колонкам уже задано свойство float: left + соответствующая ширина, что позволяет им выстраиваться в ряды. А 4-й - он на flex'ах, и чтобы им грамотно и корректно пользоваться, надо всё-таки понимать, что такое флексбоксы и как они работают

Comment: Я понял, благодарю.